# Why is the oriented $G$-homotopy type of a $G$-complex uniquely determined by the periodicity generator?

Tags: surgery-theory

Say we have a periodicity generator $e \in H^k(BG)$. I can show that we then have a $(k-1)$-dimensional $G$-complex $X$ with free $G$-action. It's also not that difficult to see that it has trivial $G$-action on $H^{k-1}(BG)$ with $e(X)=e$. However, my mentor claims that $X$'s oriented $G$-homotopy type must be uniquely determined by the periodicity generator $e$. I just can't see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $EG\to BG$ to be the universal $G$ principal bundle of $G$. Fix $X$ to be an homotopy representation of $G$ with free action of dimension $n-1$. Considerer the fiber bundle $p : EG\times_G X \to BG$. This one is a spherical bundle. If $G$ acts on $H^{n-1} (X,\mathbf{Z})$ then we have an exact sequence $$\ldots \to H^k (BG) \to H^{k+n} (BG) \to H^{k+n}(EG\times_G X)\ldots \to$$ where the first map is noted $e_X$ and the second one is the one induced by $p$. The map $e_X$ is just the multiplication by the Euler class $e(X)\in H^{n}(BG)$. Defining this Euler class requires an orientation of our sphere bundle, and this is given by an element of $H^{n-1}(X)$ that generates $H^{n-1}(X)$. The projection $EG\times_G X \to X/G$ is a fibration with contractible fibres all equal to $EG$ so that you can show that it is an homotopy equivalence. Now, as $X/G$ is of dimension $n-1$, you get that $EG\times_G$'s cohomology vanishes in degree $k\geq n$, and then $e_X$ is an isomorphism for all $k>0$. Finally, as ($\mathbf{Z}$-valued) cohomologies of $BG$ and $G$ are the same, you see that $G$ has periodic cohomology, and that $e$ is a periodicity generator.

What you are stating, plus yours professor's statement is the reciprocal of what preceeds, and was proved by R.G. Swan in *[Periodic Resolutions for Finite Groups](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1970135?sid=21106260998233&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&uid=3739744)*, Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 72, No. 2 (Sep., 1960), pp. 267-291, and it is avalaible for free in online reading. It is its theorems A and A', and your professor's statement is consequence of results proved in the article, namely, the generalization of Schanuel's theorem.